# Can i change a slider dot from code according to the change of the given value?

Tags: flutter, slider

I move a slider and I have a value.
Is it possible, by modifying this value through another widget, to modify the slider so that there is always a correspondence between the value and the slider itself?

I mean: if I increase the value by 100, for example, i need the dot slider change too.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
  ),
  home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
 );
 }
}

 class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: 
 key);
 final String title;
 @override
 State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
double sliderValue = 50;
@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
   backgroundColor: Colors.cyan,
   appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(widget.title),
   ),
  body: Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Text(
        '${sliderValue.toStringAsFixed(1)}',
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
      ),
      Slider(
        value: sliderValue,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        divisions: 100,
        onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            sliderValue = val;
          });
        },
      ),
      Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
        children: [
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (sliderValue - 1 > -1) sliderValue -= 1;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_left),
            label: Text('Decrease'),
          ),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                if (sliderValue < 100.0) sliderValue += 1;
              });
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_right),
            label: Text('Increase'),
          )
        ],
      )
    ],
  ),
);
}
}
```

Comment: the value you type in the textfield will move the slider to that value. In this example i have considered min value 0f 0 and max of 100. If you drag the slider, the value in textfield will change. Both the widgets correspond to each other in value

Comment: First of all thank you for your answer. In my project I have two ElevatedButtom.icon (a right arrow and a left arrow) and I need to move the slider dot by pressing the buttons. In you code, if I try to change the textfield I have an exception: FormatException (FormatException: Invalid radix-10 number (at character 1)
60.02".

Comment: Code revised with ElevatedButtons. Please check now

Comment: If the answer solves your issue please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks